# Convert a PHP variable into plain text for POST url extension

Tags: php, jquery

I am having trouble converting a php variable into plain text in order to use in a jquery load more posts script. I want to run display reviews with variable ID's. When I place the PHP variable in the url extension it does not work, however when I manually insert it in plain text it works but that defeats the purpose of having variables.

```
$review_id = 155;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'reviews/'+ '<? echo $review_id; ?>',
```

I have also tried:

```
var review_id = "<? echo $_explode_url[2]; ?>";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'reviews/'+ 'review_id',
```

This works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'reviews/'+ '155',
```

Comment: Have you tried `data:{rID:<?php echo $review_id; ?>}` after `url`

Comment: You really should be using `json_encode()` around variable data being echoed into JavaScript, to ensure the correct data types are used and data is escaped properly.

Comment: `POST` data doesn't go in the URL, it sounds like you're trying to make a `GET` request.

Comment: Your example is missing the php tags to go in and out of PHP mode (`$review_id = 155;` is missing `<?php ?>` around it). Is that your problem? See the first example in my answer

Comment: have you tried echoing the value of `$review_id`? Is it returning the correct values? If your variable changes everytime you make an ajax call then you're not going to make it work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Just in terms of how php strings work:

```
url: <?php echo "'reviews/$review_id'"; ?>,
```

Also to clarify, php runs serverside.  If you hope to have this variable set in anyway other than when the page is returned (and $review_id must be known at that point) then this has no chance of working.  You would need to do that in javascript/jquery code.

Comment: It is still not producing anything. However if I manually insert the variable to test it, it works?

Comment: The variable is showing in the source code so I cannot understand how it is not connecting up.

Comment: When you look at the javascript that is rendered to the client in firebug, do you see the url correctly reflected?

Comment: Yeah it is showing up the same as it would be if I enter the variable manually and look at source code. It is wholly baffling..

Comment: So it seems that the issue is with the ajax call not occurring.  When you look at the net tab in firebug, do you see the page making a call to your server?  You are providing a relative path, so the reviews path would need to be relative to the path of the original page where this ajax call is loaded.  Probably you would want at least /...reviews so that it's relative to the server root.

Comment: It's exactly the firebug tab I described. Load the page, open firebug, click on the Net tab.  You should see an entry fore each call, that you can drill into.  If you see nothing you can refresh the page with the tab open.

Comment: Then it is working.  The server returned a 200.  It's not clear why you are using a POST from your code snippet.

Comment: I would just use a GET then and tack that on as a url parameter rather than using post.  Easier for you to test as well.  Seems that everything is working, and it's all down to your results and whatever is suppossed to happen with the response data at this point.  GL!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var review_id = "<? echo $_explode_url[2]; ?>";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'reviews/'+review_id, // <----
```

does this work?

Comment: No that doesn't work either. I am not sure if a <?php can be used within <script>

Answer (score 0):

```
var review_id = "<? echo $_explode_url[2]; ?>";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'reviews=/'+".$review_id.", // <----
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function FunctionA (review_id){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'reviews/' + review_id ,

 }
```

Call the function as this:

```
FunctionA (<?php echo $review_id ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% sure that your object will be correctly encoded for JS, you should just use `json_encode()`, it will work with any PHP type, in this case it's not needed because it's a number, but it's good practice for when it's a string and special characters need to be encoded, for example, if your string was `$reviewId = "\'Hello\'\n\"world\"";`

```
// Are you just missing the php open and close tags 
// and creating a global JS variable?
<?php $review_id = 155; ?>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'reviews/'+ <?php echo json_encode($review_id) ?>,
```

As other have noted, you could do the string concatenation in PHP instead of in JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'reviews/<?php echo $review_id ?>',
```

You could also use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo "reviews/$review_id" ?>',
```